# Android: Theme.Holo is not black

Tags: android, styles, themes

I am developing my new Android App and after I made the first layouts, I was wondering why everything is white (background) and not black like always before. So I figured out it is because of Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar. I immediately changed it to Theme.Holo but nothing changed in the Emulator.

I googled the problem and they said that your minSDK has to be 11+, so I changed it to 11,12,13,14 but nothing changed again!

What can I do to see the old and nice black theme?

Comment: Please post your manifest file.

Answer (score 7):

The values-v11 and values-v14 folders have styles.xml files in them that need to be updated in addition to the main one.

Answer (score 6):

Use `Theme.Holo`. Since you elected not to post any source code, it is impossible to indicate where you are going wrong. However, if you run an app using a theme based upon `Theme.Holo` -- such as [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/MultiView1) -- you get a dark background.

The easiest way to get `Theme.Holo` is to not specify a theme at all, as `Theme.Holo` is the default for apps with `android:targetSdkVersion` of 11 or higher and running on an API Level 11+ device.

The sample app I linked to takes a more elaborate approach, courtesy of Eclipse's code generators:

- It has `res/values/styles.xml` defining `AppTheme` as inheriting from the old dark `Theme`:
- It has `res/values/styles.xml` defining `AppTheme` as inheriting from `Theme.Holo`:
- It uses `AppTheme` in its [manifest](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ViewPager/MultiView1/AndroidManifest.xml) (which for some reason is not displaying in this answer, so you will have to settle for clicking the [link](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ViewPager/MultiView1/AndroidManifest.xml))

Hence, it will use `Theme.Holo` on API Level 11+ devices and `Theme` on older devices. Both supply a dark background.